# Create array field in jhipster using mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, jhipster, multivalue

I want create one field e.g URL in that field we can insert multiple value url that data is stored in array format using jhipster mongodb

Created getter setter of string[]url in dto.java

Answer (score 0):

With JHipster, you define your entities [as per the docs](https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/).

It's worth noting that you can't define arrays of `List`s directly, you have to create a [one-to-many relationship](https://www.jhipster.tech/managing-relationships/), eg: set up your JDL something like this:

```
entity SomeEntity {
    id String
    ...
}

entity Url {
    name String
}

relationship OneToMany {
    SomeEntity{url} to Url{parentEntity}
}
```

It's also worth noting that JHipster [does not provide a uni-direction one-to-many relationship](https://www.jhipster.tech/managing-relationships/#a-unidirectional-one-to-many-relationship) at the minute.